# Net.Mail.MailAddress and adding an email address to established variable

Tags: powershell

If I go

```
[Net.Mail.MailAddress]$email = 'mytest@domain.com'
```

Then later in my code I want to add an address. I can't figure out how to add an additional email address.

I have tried

```
[Net.Mail.MailAddress]$email = $($email,newemail@domain.com)
[Net.Mail.MailAddress]$email = $($email,"newemail@domain.com")
[Net.Mail.MailAddress]$email = "$email,newemail@domain.com"
[Net.Mail.MailAddress]$email = "$email","newemail@domain.com"
```

Comment: you've already constrained your variable to be a single `[Net.Mail.MailAddress]`, if you want an array of em then you need to `[Net.Mail.MailAddress[]]`

Comment: I think possibly more important is to address where you are using that. If you're setting up an email, and doing something like `$Message.To = $email` you'll probably need to do `$Message.To.Add($email2)` or even `$Message.To.Add('newemail@domain.com')`

Answer (score 1):

It was as simple as

```
[Net.Mail.MailAddress]$email = 'mytest@domain.com'
[Net.Mail.MailAddress[]]$email = 'mytest@domain.com','newaddress@domain.com'
```

It should be noted that I read about `$Message.To.Add($email2)` given in the comments but was not sure how to get that going in my code or get it going at all :)
Thanks
TheMadTechnician
and
Santiago Squarzon

Comment: `.Add` wouldn't work with `[Net.Mail.MailAddress[]]` because it's an array and arrays are of a fixed size. It would work using `+=` though. `.Add` would work if you were using `[System.Collections.Generic.List[Net.Mail.MailAddress]]`